# Como melhorar desempenho do select

Tags: banco-de-dados, node.js, firebird

Tenho que utilizar firebird, mas não me dou muito bem com banco de dados, fiz o select da seguinte maneira:

```
select first 5 skip ((1 - 1) * 10) distinct
 PRO.CODIGO,
 PRO.NIVEL_INTERESSE,
 PRO.DATA_RETORNO,
 PRO.RESPONSAVEL_PROSPECT,
 PRO.EMPRESA_PROSPECT,
 PRO.CIDADE_IBGE,
 PRO.VENDEDOR,
 PRO.STATUS,
 PRO.TIPO_CONTATO,
 PRO.EMAIL,
 PRO.DATA_ALTERACAO,
 PRO.DATA_CADASTRO,
 VEN.NOME as NOME_VENDEDOR,
 PRO.TELEFONE,
 (select first 1
   CODIGO
   from CAD_PROSPECTOS_PROPOSTAS WHERE PROSPECTO = PRO.CODIGO
   order by CODIGO desc) as COD_PROPOSTA,
 (select first 1
   CODIGO
   from CAD_PROSPECTOS_AGENDAMENTOS
   where PROSPECTO = PRO.CODIGO
   order by CODIGO desc) as COD_AGENDAMENTO,
 (select first 1
   CODIGO
   from CAD_PROSPECTOS_CONTRATOS
   where PROSPECTO = PRO.CODIGO
   order by CODIGO desc) as COD_CONTRATO,
 (select first 1
   CONTRATO_CONFIRMADO
   from CAD_PROSPECTOS_CONTRATOS
   where PROSPECTO = PRO.CODIGO
   order by CODIGO desc) as CONTRATO_CONFIRMADO,
 (select first 1
   NOME
   from CAD_MUNICIPIOS
   where IBGE = PRO.CIDADE_IBGE) as NOME_MUNICIPIO
 from CAD_PROSPECTOS PRO
 left join CAD_TERCEIROS VEN on PRO.VENDEDOR = VEN.CODIGO and PRO.EMPRESA = 
 VEN.EMPRESA
 left join CAD_TERCEIROS_VENDEDORES CTV on PRO.CODIGO = VEN.CODIGO and 
 PRO.EMPRESA = VEN.CODIGO
 where PRO.EMPRESA = 1 and
       PRO.ESTABELEC = 1
 order by PRO.CODIGO desc
```

Funciona perfeitamente e atende todas as minhas necessidades, único problema é que fica extremamente lento. Como eu poderia melhorar este select para que ele funcionasse mais rápido e me trazendo os mesmos dados.

Comment: esses `subselects` degradam o desempenho de maneira geral. Não pude analisar no seu caso específico, mas normalmente eu tento fugir deles quando posso, inclusive por questões de performance (meu foco é mais SQL Server e SQLite). Mas eu já tive de por um `subselect` justamente por questões de performance...

Comment: Estou tentando de alguma maneira retirar esses `sebselcts`, talvez se eu fizer em dois selects separados ajude a melhorar o desempenho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem algumas formas, mas depende da versao do firebird que vc esta rodando.
Vou te falar 3, se vc tiver problemas para implementa-las, me mande a DDL ou o proprio fdb para recriar o banco na minha maquina e te dar o select pronto e testado. 
1 - as inves de fazer subselect na clausula select, use query derivada:

```
select tabela1.campo2, sub1.campo, ....
from tabela1,
     ( select campo
        from subtabela s
       where .....
      ) as sub1
where ....
```

2 - crie stored procedures com um for:

```
 create procedure select_exemplo.....
 //....
  for
     select ...
      from ...
  do begin
    select subcampo
      from substabela
    where .....
    into :subcampo-retorno;     
    suspend;
  end
```

3 - utilizar a clausa with antes do select. Veja o link a seguir, na secao 'Common Table Expressions (“WITH ... AS ... SELECT”)' 
https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-dml-select.html#fblangref25-dml-select-cte

Comment: Realmente fiz por meio de uma procedure é já ajudou muito no desempenho, obrigado.

Comment: pode estar faltando algum indice tb.....otimizar queries realmente nao eh uma receita de bolo......eu que agradeco....e de qualquer forma, estou a disposicao.

Comment: outra coisa importante, eh q se vc ainda nao estah usando a versao 3 do firebird, recomendo fortemente a migracao. Na versao 3 mudaram a ODS, e implementaram novos formas/protocolos de autenticacao, compactacao e criptografia. Alem disso, eles falaram q o timespan das releases vai diminuir bastante, e a versao 4 jah vai ter outra ODS tb.

Comment: Infelizmente uso a versão 2.5, por conta da empresa onde trabalho, então não é fácil fazer uma mudança assim, mas agradeço a dica.

Comment: entendo perfeitamente....onde eu trabalhava tinhamos o mesmo problema, com o agravante de uso de udf, mas consegui fazer mesmo com essas e outras dificuldades.....se precisar de ajuda, soh me falar....boa sorte, amigo.